# How to make coordinate value bold?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I am tyring to make this value (16.49) bold in the bar graph. I can't seem to find any answer.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{fig:table}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
%axis line style={draw=none}, 
major grid style={dotted,black},
width=0.33\textwidth,
height=0.33\textwidth,
xbar, xmin=0, xmax=70,
yticklabel style={align=center},
xlabel={DEF \%},
xlabel style={font=\smaller},
symbolic y coords={%
                    {a},
                    {b},
                    {c},
                    {d},
                    {e},
                    {f},
                    {g},
                    {g},
                    {i},               
                    {j}
                    },
ytick=data,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[zerofill, fixed, precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
every node near coord/.append style={font=\smaller},
nodes near coords align={horizontal},
ytick=data,
]
\addplot [fill=gray!90,draw=black!70] 
coordinates {(16.49,{a})
            (17.60,{b})
            (26.37,{c})
            (29.0,{d})
            (29.83,{e})
            (29.99,{f})
            (36.22,{g})
            (43.80,{h})
            (49.55,{i})
            (54.50,{j})       
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Abcs}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet compilable, so that we don't have to guess which packages and document class you are using. There seems to be a mistake in the values for `symbolic y coords`, since `{h}` is missing while `{g}` exists twice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `coordinate style/.condition` to format a single value differently than the other. I adjusted your original code a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    xbar, xmin=0, xmax=70,
    yticklabel style={align=center},
    xlabel={Log-Average Miss Rate \%},
    xlabel style={font=\smaller},
    symbolic y coords={%
        {a},
        {b},
        {c},
        {d},
        {e},
        {f},
        {g},
        {h},
        {i},               
        {j}
    },
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathprintnumber[zerofill, fixed, precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    },
    coordinate style/.condition={x == 16.49}{font=\smaller\boldmath},
    coordinate style/.condition={x != 16.49}{font=\smaller},
]
\addplot [fill=gray!90,draw=black!70] 
    coordinates {
        (16.49,{a})
        (17.60,{b})
        (26.37,{c})
        (29.0,{d})
        (29.83,{e})
        (29.99,{f})
        (36.22,{g})
        (43.80,{h})
        (49.55,{i})
        (54.50,{j})       
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

An easy solution for also making the relevant tick bold, would be to explicitly define the tick labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    xbar, xmin=0, xmax=70,
    yticklabel style={align=center},
    xlabel={Log-Average Miss Rate \%},
    xlabel style={font=\smaller},
    symbolic y coords={%
        {a},
        {b},
        {c},
        {d},
        {e},
        {f},
        {g},
        {h},
        {i},               
        {j}
    },
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels={\textbf{a},b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j},
    nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathprintnumber[zerofill, fixed, precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    },
    coordinate style/.condition={x == 16.49}{font=\smaller\boldmath},
    coordinate style/.condition={x != 16.49}{font=\smaller},
]
\addplot [fill=gray!90,draw=black!70] 
    coordinates {
        (16.49,{a})
        (17.60,{b})
        (26.37,{c})
        (29.0,{d})
        (29.83,{e})
        (29.99,{f})
        (36.22,{g})
        (43.80,{h})
        (49.55,{i})
        (54.50,{j})       
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I don't know how to thank you enough. This was driving me crazy for the last few days. lol Also, I have the following error. It doesn't affect the graph, but any thoughts? <inserted text> 
                \par 
l.336 \end{axis}
                
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will.

Comment: here's the second error. It shows up after I add cite from a to j in both y cords and coords. {pgfstrokecolor}{\@tempswatrue \@citex }\def \reserved@b {\@tempswafalse \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \XC@definec@lor was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.336 \end{axis}
                
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

Comment: It doesn't affect the plot though.

Comment: @abcs_of_plots Well, the first error is typically the one you should care about. It says that there is an unmatched `}` on line 336. You should look for it. It is hard to help you without having your full code. I cannot reproduce this error, since you did not provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)
which you really should do. Also, I think, you should ask a new question about this, if this is not related to the question (which I think is the case here, if the plot is not affected).

Comment: Agreed. I will mark this as solved.

Comment: Would you be able to help with one thing? How can I make 'a' bold in above plot?

Comment: @user2661372 See my edit.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: yep, upvoted it. I think it will reflect after I have 15 pts.

Comment: Jasper, I created another topic for the error I mentioned. Would you be able to take a look? thank you so much!!!